# How to create a functional or where clause from a list of where clauses in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I have the following where clauses :

```
q)).tst.wc
(max$["b"];((/:;like);`Col1;(enlist;"0009D000";"00080000")))
(like;`Col2;,"B0000000999")
```

I want to crate the following query:

```
,(|;(max$["b"];((/:;like);`Col1;(enlist;"0009D000";"00080000")));(like;`Col2;,"B0000000999"))
```

I tried

```
(or;.tst.wc) //doesn't work 

(or; first each .tst.wc) // doesn't work 

(or;.tst.wc 0;.tst.wc 1) // works
```

however I cannot use the last one because I don't know how many where clauses will be there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to share some input / expected output tables? It's difficult to test solutions without them

Answer (score 1):

You can just append them to `or` as follows:

```
q)(or),.tst.wc
|
($["b"];((/:;like);`Col1;(enlist;"0009D000";"00080000")))
(like;`Col2;,"B0000000999")

q)(or;.tst.wc 0;.tst.wc 1)~(or),.tst.wc
1b
```

EDIT: if you have an unknown number of where clauses and they all need an "or" between them all then you can use:

```
(or;;)/[.tst.wc]
```

however this where clause will fast become inefficient as nested "or"s are not optimal query filtering - each clause needs to be applied to the entire length of the table

Answer (score 0):

so the best I could find so far was :

```
{[x;y]$[x~();(or;y);x,enlist y]}/[();.tst.wc]
```

... ready to accept and upvote a better answer ...

Answer (score 0):

What about using `any`? If I understand you correctly you are creating any number of `or` conditions.

```
t:([]a:til 10;b:`a`b`c`d`e`f`g`h`i`j;c:10*til 10);

.tst.wc:((=;`a;0);(=;`b;enlist `d);(=;`c;90));

?[t;enlist ((any),enlist (enlist),.tst.wc);0b;()!()]
a b c
------
0 a 0
3 d 30
9 j 90

// also works with one
.tst.wc2:enlist (=;`a;0);

?[t;enlist ((any),enlist (enlist),.tst.wc2);0b;()!()]
a b c
-----
0 a 0
```